# Команда RMDIR даёт код выполнения, но не ERRORLEVEL. И как его (код) получить для обработки далее?

Tags: windows, cmd

Команда rmdir (OS Windows) даёт по завершению значения статусов:

```
Possible exit status values are:
0 - Successful completion.
1 - Failure because directory is not a directory, or because it still contains files or subdirectories.
2 - Failure because of an invalid command line option, or no directory names specified.
```

Но как их принять\обработать? Или я что-то не то вычитал? Допустим в реализации для сообщения пользователю об ошибке, а в положительном случае для сообщении о верном завершении операции?
К примеру с ErrorLevel всё более-менее понятно: `if ErrorLevel 1 goto Error`
А как быть с rmdir? Как, допустим, перенаправить при ошибке?

Comment: А чем не устраивает конвейер команд: выполнить удаление и выход, иначе реагировать на ошибку: **rmdir 11111 && exit & @echo error**

Answer (score 0):

```
rd %foldername% 2>&1 | find "." > nul
```

Результат пригоден для проверки на errorlevel.

Answer (score 0):

`Exit code` это то же самое, что `error level`. Одно и то же, просто названное в разных местах по-разному. `Exit code` это термин WinAPI - целое число, которой программа возвращает оператором `return` или вызовом `exit` (консольная программа), либо как аргумент функции `ExitProcess` (оконная программа).

Это же самое число, возвращенное программой, оболочка Windows называет `error level`. Общим соглашением является что 0 сигнализирует об успешном завершении программы, а ненулевое значение сигнализирует об ошибке. Программа может возвращать разные ненулевые коды для разных ошибок, но большинство не заморачиваются и просто возвращают единицу для любой ошибки.

Поскольку код ошибки может быть не единицей, а вообще произвольным, надежней будет сравнивать `ErrorLevel` не с единицей, а с нулем. Если, конечно, вас не интересует какой-то конкретный код ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Код ошибки возвращаемый RD помещается в ERRORLEVEL после применения операторов конвейера.
НАпример:

```
ver >NUL
rmdir Folder_Name ||REM
if ErrorLevel 1 goto Error
```

ver >NUL сбрасывает ErrorLevel в 0.

Answer (score -1):

Так как `rmdir` не меняет `ERRORLEVEL`, можно воспользоваться операцией ИЛИ (`||`).
Это не позволит получить код ошибки, но можно проверить 0 или не 0.

```
rmdir testdir || goto :error
```

Похожий вопрос на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137702/rd-exits-with-errorlevel-set-to-0-on-error-when-deletion-fails-etc/11137825

Comment: errorlevel вообще-то равен exit status и это не переменная %errorlevel%

Comment: Хм.. не знаю почему минус, но у меня реализация получилась:
`rmdir "%AppData%\1C\1Cv82" /S /Q || goto Error_1  
goto Normal_1  
...`
[/code]